# Sticky sidebar that scrolls vertically when content overflows vertically

Tags: html, css

**Desired UX:**

[image]

**JSFiddle**: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/2xf4o69L/19/)

****HTML** and **CSS****:

```css
#body{
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#toc-container{
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  height: 100%;
  
}

#toc{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="toc-container">
    <div id="toc">
      <p>
        This should scroll when you hover over it, and only when you hover over it.
      </p>
      <hr>
      <p>TOC entries</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  This should scroll whenever *not* hovering over the TOC / sidebar. <hr>
</div>
```

**The challenge**: The sidebar is vertically sticking, but is not scrolling on hover. How can the TOC be styled such that it sticks to the top edge of the viewport, and scrolls vertically *only* when scrolled directly, *never* when the body is scrolled?

Comment: Did you try adding `overflow-y: auto;` on `#toc` ?